# Explaining/Describing the code below or above the code?

Tags: discussion, code, writing-style

Is there a preferred style on this site, where to put explanations of the code one posted?

Should it be done like this:

> Some explanation above
>
> ```
> if (x != y)
>     //do something
> ```

or like this:

> ```
> if (x != y)
>     //do something
> ```
>
> some explanation below

Or is this completely irrelevant?

Comment: Either is acceptable but **in my opinion**, it's better to state the issue in words *first* and then demonstrate it.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, plus it helps to understand the code which, if it's on SO, is quite likely to be badly-formatted with single-letter identifiers.  Getting some understading of what it's supposed to do, and how, reduces the chance that I will just downvote it, close as 'unclear' and move on.

Comment: I quite often introduce the code fragment with words such as _'You currently have code like this'_ followed by the code from the question, and then the explanation. This protects the answer from edits to the question making the answer seem inaccurate/irrelevant. The answer may now be irrelevant because the question changed, but at least the answer is self-consistent with some version of the question and latecomers can see at least that the answer was at one time relevant (I hope).  Sometimes the preamble will include a brief outline of the issue, and the postamble then amplifies the details.

Comment: Imposing a coding style on every single user that visits Stack Overflow is even more of a pipe dream than getting everyone on your individual *project* to adopt a coding style.

Comment: Is this question salvageable by an edit, or should I leave it like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a programming problem and you want a colleague or friend sitting next to you to help you, what would you do? You would ... browse through the code and *simultaneously* tell what's going on. This isn't very well supported by the Stack Exchange post format; I'd rather copy entire files from an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) than having to weed out explanations every 4 lines of code. (Of course, good comments in the code can be helpful too.)

So I'd rather follow the practice used by most coding books; generally, they will tell what a piece of code should do *above* the code itself, and optionally put some notes *below* the code discussing the finer points.

But I think the most important part is not the placing of the explanation, but the fact that it's clear, unambiguous, and not `formatted as code`.

Comment: Thanks, I just used `this` to make more visible where the examples begin and end. Normally, I don't use it when explaining code.

Comment: Great, keep it up! It's just one of my [pet peeves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/295232) and it's IMO always worth repeating.

Comment: I addressed that with an edit to the question.